# Logical error in code that only allows one question to be asked (I think) in bash script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, logic

I am trying to create a code that outputs a missplet word and the user has to type in the correct spelling of the word. However, at the moment it is only outputing a single question, there is about 10 in total. At the moment it outputs correctly the first question, input the correct spelling get told its correct, then the quiz ends.

Example (word file):

```
mispelled, misspelled 
alot, a lot
your'e, you're 
Seperate, Separate
Occurence, Occurrence
```

The code goes as follows:

```
question=0
i=0
score=0


for (( i=0; i<$question; i++ )); do
  current_pair=${shuffled_word_pairs[$i]}
  misspelled_word=$(echo "$current_pair" | cut -d',' -f1)
  correct_word=$(echo "$current_pair" | cut -d',' -f2)

  if [[ "$misspelled_word" == "" ]]; then
    continue
  fi

  echo "Question $questions: What is the correct spelling of of '$misspelled_word'?"

  read -p "Your answer: " answer

  while [ "$answer" != "$correct_word" ]; do
    if [[ "$answer" == "skip" ]]; then
      echo "Question skipped."
      break
    elif [[ "$answer" == "help"* ]]; then
      echo "Hint: The first letter of the correct word is '$(echo "$correct_word" | cut -         c1)'."
      read -p "Your answer: " answer
    elif [[ "$answer" == "many"* ]]; then
      echo "Incorrect. The correct answer is '$correct_word'."
      read -p "Your answer: " answer
    elif [ "$allow_multiple_attempts" = true ]; then
      read -p "Incorrect. Please try again: " answer
    else
      echo "Incorrect. The correct answer is '$correct_word'."
      break
    fi
  done

  if [ "$answer" = "$correct_word" ]; then
    echo "Correct!"
    score=$((score++))
  fi

  questions=$((questions+1))
 done
```

Example output:
What is the the correct spelling of alot?
Your answer: a lot
Correct! (1/1)

Your score 1 out of 5
Your time: 6 seconds

I looked on both shellscript and tried re-organsing the strcuture of the code but neithier seemed to do the trick for me. Shellscript said there were no major errors but rather just info points on the code.

Any help would be greatly appreicated,
Thank you

Comment: `i<$question` ?

Comment: Sorry, i just added the arguments section, I had i=0, questions=0 before this. Thank you

Comment: `question` != `questions`

Comment: Fixed that up in the code and the same issue is still occurring sorry.

Comment: Update the code in the question and add sample data for `shuffled_word_pairs`, and include a verbatim transcript of output from running precisely that code, so that someone can just run the code to repeat your result.

Comment: Thank you, I just did that, except I could not take a photo/copy-paste as that is a whole other issue at the moment.

Comment: `question=0;  for (( i=0; i<$question; i++ )); do:` after the first run, i (now 1) is greater than question (0).       Also, I can't not:  '*missplet*'.   :-D

Comment: @mcalex No, the for loop will not even run once as shown: 0<0 is never true.

Comment: The code shown here still does not match the actual code you are having problems with. The code in the question if run will produce no output. Even if `question` were initially set to 1, `question`!=`questions`, so will still terminate after a single iteration.

Comment: It would make more sense to have something like: `maxq=10; for (( i=1; i<maxq; i++ )); do ...; done` and use `$i` instead of `$questions`, and never try to increment `maxq` inside the loop.

Comment: Showing contents of a word file is not the same as initialising the array `shuffled_word_pairs`. So the code shown can still not be run as-is by anyone who wants to help you.